# DB2 SQL: within group, assign value of column 2 when column 1 is at maximum, to each row

Tags: db2, partition

I have data which looks like this, for **one** group, i.e. there are more data like this stacked on top of eachother:

[image]

Now, within each group, I want to make a new column called "relationship", where I take the value of *factor* (when year=2018 (maximum)), and take each value of factor of each row and divide by the factor value of 2018.
I can do this in a two step manner with a CLT expression, that is all good.

**edit**: what I want is something like this:

select data.*
,first(factor) over(partition by group order by group, year desc)

or

select data.*
,factor over(where max(year))

Comment: where is the group column?

Comment: Sorry, I might have formulated myself unclearly. What you see of the data above, the image, is one group, say Group=1. Within each group, I want to do the explained operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I understood your question is differnt to result of the relationship column you provide.
Here is an example - maybe you have to adhust the calcuation (in case I missunderstood you)

```
SELECT group
     , year
     , age
     , factor
     , factor / first_value(factor) OVER(PARTITION BY group  ORDER BY year desc) as relationship
  FROM test_r
```

Comment: brilliant, I did not know of the first_value function, thank you very much!
I assume I can turn the fraction around without any problem, so this solves it completely as I see it :)